# Selecting from a View in Subsonic causes an error!

Tags: subsonic

Sorry if this seems a silly questions but can you select from a view in subsonic?
I have a view called fixturesinfo and I am running this subsonic query:

```
  FixturesInfoCollection fixtures = new SubSonic.Select().From<FixturesInfo>()
                .Where(FixturesInfo.Columns.FixtureDate).IsGreaterThan(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3))
                .ExecuteAsCollection<FixturesInfoCollection>();
```

When I run it I get an error dbo.FixturesInfo.
This happens with all views.
Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks Bex

Answer (score 1):

Worked it out..
I am using two database connection string and it appears as it was a generic select it wasn't picking the right one.
Instead if I do this:

```
  FixturesInfoCollection fixtures =new FixturesInfoCollection()
                    .Where(FixturesInfo.Columns.FixtureDate,
                           Comparison.GreaterThan, DateTime.Now)
                           .OrderByAsc(FixturesInfo.Columns.FixtureDate).Load();
```

It works

Comment: another hint: Always use YourNamespace.DB.Select()... instead of SubSonic().Select()... Every subsonic generated DAL has a DB class that sets up a repository with the right connection for you.

Comment: Ahh.. thank you..! I am only just starting out with subsonic so not undestanding everything yet.